# Theme for SearchView in ActionBar

Tags: android, searchview

I have a `SearchView` in an `ActionBar`.

This `SearchView` icon is black, and text is black too whereas my icon is white !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I would like my SearchView be white.

Comment: did you tried searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); ?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for. I need the search glass to be white, and the edit text too

Comment: @JaredBurrows I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: It's not for AppCompat7

Comment: Find SearchView Widget in this [Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in menu.xml add,

```
    <item
android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:title="Search"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

in style.xml you need to apply style like this

```
    <style name=”Theme.MyTheme” parent=”Theme.AppCompat”>
    <item name=”searchViewStyle”>@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name=”MySearchViewStyle” parent=”Widget.AppCompat.SearchView”>
    <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <item name="queryBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
    <item name="submitBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Close button icon -->
    <item name="closeIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Go/commit button icon -->
    <item name="goIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Voice search button icon -->
    <item name="voiceIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
    <item name="commitIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">...</item>
</style>
```

and finally in menifest file:

```
    <application...
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
```

Ref: [Android appcompact library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)
Hope this helped!

Comment: It is not working for me.. I have followed the same code but instead of applying theme to entire application, I have applied to my activity as

<activity
            android:name=".MenuScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>